# Can we find an $x, y : x < y$ and $x, y > 0$ and $\lfloor \frac{n}{x}\rfloor$ < $\lfloor \frac{n}{y}\rfloor$ for some integer $n > 0$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, algorithms

I know there are no solutions when we have just the fraction without the floor, but how do we consider solutions when the floor is there?

Answer (score 1):

The floor function being monotonous (non-strictly) increasing, 
$$\frac nx>\frac ny\implies \lfloor\frac nx\rfloor\ge\lfloor\frac ny\rfloor.$$

Answer (score 1):

Still no solution. Functions  $f_{n}:x\rightarrow\frac{n}{x}
 $ are all decreasing on $\mathbb{R}^{+}
 $ . Fuction $g:Z\rightarrow\left\lfloor Z\right\rfloor 
 $ isn't strictly monotonic, but still monotonic. So, if  $0<x<y$, then  $ \frac{n}{y} <\frac{n}{x} $ and $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{y}\right\rfloor \leqq\left\lfloor \frac{n}{x}\right\rfloor $